# How to correctly translate an expression from SSRS to Power BI

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am in the task of migrating a report from SSRS to Power BI, now I find the following expression or formula in SSRS:

```
=Sum(
IIf(Fields!DateSend.Value < Today(),
iif(Fields!TypeRecord.Value=1, Fields!Tons.Value, Nothing)
,nothing)
)
```

I have tried transcribing it to a new column in Power BI as follows:

```
New Column = SUM(IF(Query1[DateSend] < TODAY(),
IF(Query[TypeRecord]= 1, Query1[Tons],0),0))
```

But I get at the end a syntax error that tells me the following:

> The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to enter the formula correctly in Power BI.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your data structure but I would guess in the SSRS report the expression was not used a the detail level. In Power BI I would create new column without using SUM so it is just evaluating for each row, then in your visualisation, aggregate that new column.

Comment: Try what you say but the `SUM` is not performed, so I see the need to use the SUM function, any other suggestions or is there any additional step that I need?

Comment: The SSRS expression can (should) be boiled down to `=SUM(IIF((Fields!DateSend.Value < Today() AND Fields!TypeRecord.Value=1, 1, 0))` if that helps.

Comment: @HannoverFist This comment doesn't help, what I require is to pass the expression from SSRS to DAX in Power BI, the expression in SSRS no longer matters to me, the important thing now is the function in DAX

Comment: But you are trying to create a new column. Custom Columns can only 'see' the data that is on the same row so you cannot use a SUM across rows. If you remove the sum from your new column, the calculation will be performed on every row. Then in the visualisation you can SUM your New Column. It might be that you actually need to create a new measure, not a new column. If this does not help, you will need to show an example of your query's data and the expected outcome in your visualisation.

Comment: @AlanSchofield 
So I can create a measure in one time of a column, if it will allow me to do the sum with a measure?

Comment: edit your question to show your data and what you expect to see in the output.